# Java out of memory on 64-bit jvm

Tags: java, memory, jvm, out-of-memory

I have got a problem. My program is really big and java is throwing OutOfMemoryException.
In `.bat` file, I have got the following:

```
java -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx1500m -Xbootclasspath/p:../libs/l2ft.jar -cp config/xml;../libs/*; l2ft.gameserver.GameServer
```

Java is using 6 GB of my RAM, next 6 GB is not used.

I typed `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");` and it says that I am using 64-bit JVM.

Comment: Try increasing Xmx (max heap). Your current setting is a just under 1.5GB.

Comment: How do you know that it is using 6GB of RAM? and what do you mean by "next 6 GB is not used"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set the maximum heap size to 1500m and while the JVM can use a little more than that ~200 MB, that's all you limited the process to.

Try instead to limit your progress to around 5 GB. (You want to leave some memory for overhead and the OS)

```
-mx5g
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the options before `Xbootclasspath` this:

```
java -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx8g -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

This will make it use more memory and will also make sure it uses as little memory as possible to address the objects in a 64bits machine.

The `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` makes the perm gem space larger (which you will probably need as you're using a lot of heap memory) and the `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` will make it use 32bits addressing for objects, instead of 64bits, as a 8gb heap can be correctly addressed with 32bits, so it makes you use less memory for allocating objects.

Comment: I'm curious, why did this get downvoted? Is there something wrong with this answer?

Comment: Who knows? There was another answer that was also correct and got downvoted. Looks like the owner deleted it.

Comment: IMHO setting MaxPermSize in this case is somewhat premature opitimization. There is no indication so far, that topic starter suffers from insufficient PermGen.